# Doing something during a button is pressed in Windows Phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8

How can I do something (I want to increment a variable and display it on the screen) during someone pressed the button. Actually there is no event called OnPressed for a button in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 2):

The `Button` has a `Click` event that you can handle and use to perform your logic.

In order to execute logic for the duration of the press, handle the `ManipulationStarted` and `ManipulationEnded` events.

Comment: That is right, but I want to count during the button is pressend and not only step by step.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the click event, you can use Tap event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your button will handle the event and prevent it from bubbling - if that wasn't the case you could use MouseLeftButtonDown/Up events to do this.
However there is a way to get around this and still get the event by using the more tedious UIElement.AddHandler method.
Ex:
myButton.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(myMouseEventHandlerMethod), true);

The last bit ('true') is important since this overrides the event bubbling. 'myMouseEventHandlerMethod' is the method that you usually would use for handling a MouseLeftButtonDown event.
Handling 'Up' is the same thing. You probably also want to handle "Leave", or use CaptureMouse() when down triggers.